# Can I install chromium on windows and transfer bookmarks in my chromium to google chrome or FireFox?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, sync, bookmarks

I had Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop and had some bookmarks on chromium. Now I want to know how can I get those bookmarks on a windows laptop? I have google chrome and also FireFox on my windows laptop, but I can not get bookmarks from my ubuntu. Is it possible to install Chromium on windows? If so, can you please tell me from where I can install that. The problem is that my laptop with Ubuntu is not working now.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  I've had no issues transferring chromium (*or firefox too*) configuration/profiles from one machine to another (*even where they are running different OSes, though I'm not a windows user*) but I just move the configuration on a *file level* (*thus ignoring even package differences*).

Comment: Is this question about one-time transfer of bookmarks or continuous syncing bookmarks between the mentioned OS/Apps?

Comment: one time transfer

Comment: " Is it possible to install Chromium on windows? " Why ask users that for the most part do not use windows or chromium on windows? ;-) See https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Bookmark Manager" in Chromium and use "Export Bookmarks" in the menu (3 dots top right).

Transfer the exported bookmarks to your Windows Laptop.

In Google-Chrome, open the "Bookmark Manager" and use "Import Bookmarks" from the menu (3 dots top right). Now select the transferred bookmark file.

**Reminder:** This imports **ALL** bookmarks from Chromium.

**Reminder:** Make Backup of the Google-Chrome Bookmarks, before you import the Chromium Bookmarks, in case it does not work as you think.

Google-Chrome is the Chromium for Windows. Google-Chrome hast the same Code basis plus some Google Cloud Additions. If you want to have a "Google-Free-Chrome" in windows, use Edge.

Comment: Is it possible to install a Chromium on windows?